# How to display google maps on click of a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

This code `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`runs only when i reload/refresh the page. However i want it to display either on a click of a button or when the page opens in the browser ? How do i do that

```
  <script>
    function initialize() {
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: chicago
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
      });
      ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try attaching the event listener to a different element:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('myButton'), 'click', initialize);
```

See [addDomListener documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents).

Comment: thanks a lot ...i added an event to the button as show above and it works fine on my computer. However when i try to open it on my Andriod phone it would just not load the map i can just see the button. Does it not support on mobile apps ?

Comment: Have a look at this question, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515509/google-maps-api-v3-in-android If I've successfully answered your original question please can you mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Jon, Please do you know how to handle cases whereby initialize is not executed when the window loads but instead, it's attached to multiple elements, whereas when each of the element is clicked, an interactive map will be displayed based on the lat and lng attached to that element